# How do I fully install Ubuntu after previously installing it dualy with windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm very new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu on my laptop with dual boot alongside Windows 8. Now I would like to replace windows 8 fully with Ubuntu. Should I go through the installation process all over again? Will doing this erase all of the programs I have already installed? I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you dont need to install ubuntu again. You can simply format the partition in which your windows reside and it will remove it. Use `gparted` for that. After formatting the windows partition do this to remove it from grub(os selection menu) too,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```